# Schema formatting in Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am new at this language, and I am trying to create a schema for data that was in a excel spreadsheet and downloaded to a Text file.

> (Text file is attached)

Please note I have no java knowledge so this is all Pig. 
Can someone assist helping me format this properly to  match the  schema and remove the 
 commas in the numeric values ?

My attempted code:

```
sales2000 = LOAD '2000rssales1.txt'  USING PigStorage()
AS (field1:chararray,field2:chararray,field3:int,field4:int,field5:int,
field6:chararray,field7:chararray,field8:chararray,field9:chararray,field10:chararray,
field12:chararray,field13:chararray,field14:chararray,field15:int)
```

> ```
>  `The field I would like to do calculations on is field15  [![text.sales.data][1]][1]`
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Load it into one field say `line:charrarray` and replace the ',' and """.Then you can split the fields using ' ' and use the 15th field for your calculations.

```
A = LOAD '2000rssales1.txt' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(REPLACE(line,"\"",''),',','');
C = FOREACH B GENERATE STRSPLIT($0,' ',15); -- If your columns are tab separated use '\\t' instead of ' ' in strsplit.
```

Alternatively you can use CSVExcelStorage() as well to load the records.Download piggybank.jar and register it using the path where you download it.

```
REGISTER /downloaded_path/piggybank.jar;
A = LOAD '2000rssales1.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage('\t')
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0..$13,REPLACE($14,',',''); -- Replace the ',' with space for the 15th field;
DUMP B;
```